# Blur with alpha transparency

Tags: transparency, blur

I'm writing a simple box blur for a graphics library.
The formula makes the average of a range of pixels by adding the ARGB amounts and then dividing by the blur range

For example, with a blur range of 3;

```
pixel1 FF FF 00 00 +
pixel2 FF 00 FF 00 +
pixel3 FF 00 00 FF
/ 3 =
result FF 55 55 55
```

Which is correct.
A typical result shows as;

[image]

However, I am having difficulty with coming up with a formula to blur an image with alpha transparency.
The formula above gives this result for a yellow box on a transparent background;

[image]

You can see that the yellow is surrounded by black colour - because the red and green are being diminished to 0. The result should actually look like so;

[image]

So; the formula of `(pixel + pixel + pixel) / range` is not working for alpha-blended images.

Can anyone please give a correct formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gaussian blur with transparency](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/gaussian-blur-with-transparency)

Answer (score 7):

Two suggestions:

1. If your data is from an image you are displaying on a standard monitor, the chances are it is (or you are implicitly assuming that it's) in sRGB format. This [means that the colour components are not linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_sRGB_transfer_function_(%22gamma%22)). Ideally, you should first map into a linear colour space, do your filtering (e.g. blurring) operations, and then map back.
   *(If you just want to try a cheap and cheerful approach, squaring each of the R G B components is not a terrible approach to "linearise" the values

   - obviously, use sqrt() to map back)*.
     The alpha channel can be assumed to be linear.
2. Once in linear colour space, the next thing you want to do before filtering is to convert the pixels to a pre-multiplied-alpha format (AKA "*associated colour*").
   Basically, given 8bpc {A,R,G,B} pixel input, produce  {A, A*R/255, A*G/255, A*B/255}.  You then do your averaging on this premultiplied data as above on all four channels, and then map back by dividing through by the resulting alpha (if A=0 then, choose, RGB=0).

This *should* produce a better result. 
For more info I suggest reading through Jim Blinn's ["Compositing, Part1: Theory"](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs248-02/blinn_theory.pdf).
Particularly, note the line "*Additionally, we must use associated colors for any filtering or interpolation operations*"

*Update*: Seems I've posted a [similar answer before](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/5517/209)